# jQuery UI Autocomplete - IE6 lockup

Tags: jquery-ui, internet-explorer-6, jquery-ui-autocomplete

Before you say it, I know, IE6 is dead and it smells like it's dead. However my client has a closed network, all their machines are run only IE6, so that 100% of my user base :/

I'm using jQuery UI and the autocomplete widget, it performs well in Firefox however on IE6, even for a small list of items (here 5, returned by json with an item and a description) it's locking up the browser when I mouse over them. Applying the css seems like it may be the cause.

```
    $( "#searchTest" ).autocomplete({
 source: function( request, response ) {
  $.ajax({
   url: "index.pl",
   dataType: "json",
   data: {
    term: request.term
   },
   success: function( data ) {
    response( $.map( data.items, function( item ) {
     return {
      label: item.id + ' - ' + item.label,
      value: item.id
     }
    }));
   }
  });
 },
 minLength: 2
});
```

I can even kind of replicate the problems in IE6 using the [online demos](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/), albeit to a much lesser extent, it's just slow it doesn't hang up the browser. 
If anyone can make any suggestions for improving performance in IE6 I'd be very happy to hear them. I'm using the default style sheet from the Themeroller. Thanks

Comment: Doh!

I was using a plugin to add round corners to IE6:

http://dillerdesign.com/experiment/DD_roundies/

I commented this out and it's working way better! The plugin in question is now EOL (my bad for not checking this). The client will have to live with a functional system, but no round corners till they change browser versions.

Comment: You could add your comment as the answer and accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doh! I was using a plugin to add round corners to IE6: http://dillerdesign.com/experiment/DD_roundies/

I commented this out and it's working way better! The plugin in question is now EOL (my bad for not checking this). The client will have to live with a functional system, but no round corners till they change browser versions.